# NetworkError: Connection failure due to HTTP 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I am trying to pass values from my jQuery to my `duplicateFoldersAndFiles` function I have in GS, these values were retrieved by calling `generateFolderTree` function also on GS and it worked fine.

However, when I call `duplicateFoldersAndFiles`, I get an error:

> NetworkError: Connection failure due to HTTP 0

and my values are also not getting passed. How can I remedy this?
Here's my code.

jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var destFolder = false;
var canClick = true;
var text;
var textDest;
$(function(){
$("#selectFolder").click(runMyFunction);
});
function runMyFunction(){
if(canClick){
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(successCallback)
.withFailureHandler(showError)
.generateFolderTree();
canClick = false;
}
}

function showError(error) {
    console.log(error);
    window.alert('An error has occurred, please try again.');
  }
  
  function onSuccess() {
  console.log( "text " + text + " other " + textDest);
  }
  
  function successCallback(returnedArray)
  {
    console.log("returnedArray" + returnedArray);
    var folders = returnedArray;
   console.log("folders" + folders);
    var i = 0;
    //row;
    for( i=0; i<folders.length;i++)
    {
       console.log("i = " + i);
   var row = $('<p><tr><button class = "selectedFolder">' + folders[i] + '</button></tr></p>');
    $("#source").append(row.html());
    }
  }
 
  $('#source').on('click', 'button.selectedFolder', function(){
  if (!destFolder){
   text = $(this).text();
  $('#sourceFolder').text(text);
  } 
  else{
   textDest = $(this).text();
  $('#destinationFolder').text(textDest);
  }
  });

$('#destFolder').on('click', function(){
  destFolder = true;
$('#source').empty();
//alert('boof');
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(successCallback)
.withFailureHandler(showError)
.generateFolderTree();
});
$('#copy').on('click', function(){
//alert('boof');
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
.withFailureHandler(showError)
 
.duplicateFoldersAndFiles(text, textDest);
});
</script>
```

code.gs

```
function duplicateFoldersAndFiles(text, textDest) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var mySource = text;
var myDestination = textDest;
ui.alert(mySource);
}
```